# Check for value of input on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to check if an input contains anything in it upon the press of a button. It only seems to be checking the value upon the first load of the website. It is not detecting any values typed into the input even if the button is pressed again and again. I have tested this by setting the input value to something at default, which gave me a success. I am stumped as to why this is happening.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label>Goals:</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-box" id="goals" />
    <input
      type="button"
      name="submit"
      value="Submit"
      class="button"
      id="submit"
    />
  </body>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Gather Inputs
let goals = document.getElementById("goals").value;
console.log("goals");
$("#submit").click(function() {
  // Check Goals Input
  if (goals === "") {
    console.log("fail");
  } else {
    window.print();
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to check the value of the input _within_ the click function

Comment: ah ha, I knew something was off thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to gather the inputs *within* the `click()` function.

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  // Gather Inputs
  let goals = document.getElementById("goals").value;
  console.log("goals");
  // Check Goals Input
  if (goals === "") {
    console.log("fail");
  } else {
    window.print();
  }
});
```